# Best approach to store complex calculations and execute them (MySQL, PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a bunch of calculations to run on a set of data.

I have a table with many coordinates for example:

```
template_id = S.02.01.02.01, 
row_id : R1010, 
column_id : C1030
```

Each of these coordinates will have a value example of 1569834.00. There are many such template, row, column combinations and each of these represents a key metric example: **assets_holdings** or something.

Now, there are key metrics that could have complex calculation for example:

```
assets_loans_on_policies = (S.02.01.02.01,R0010,C1030) + (S.02.01.02.01,R0020,C1040) + (S.02.01.02.01, R0030,C1040) - (S.02.01.02.01,R0040,C1050) / (S.02.01.02.01,R0050,C1060)
```

And there are many such calculations on various template:row: col combinations.

These template, row, column and the value is stored in a MySQL table, see structure below

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
id      value           template_id         row_id      column_id
---------------------------------------------------------------------    
2       123.000         S.02.01.02.01       R0010       C1030
3       4563453.000     S.02.01.02.01       R0010       C0010
4       342342.000      S.02.01.02.01       R0020       C0010
5       12313.000       S.02.01.02.01       R0030       C0010
6       889.000         S.02.01.02.01       R0040       C0010
7       0.000           S.02.01.02.01       R0050       C0010
8       12132.000       S.02.01.02.01       R0060       C0010
9       20546227.000    S.02.01.02.01       R0070       C0010
10      1638667.000     S.02.01.02.01       R0080       C0010
```

The issue is, this could be done in MySQL but there is a ton of these coordinates and calculations so very quickly the query becomes complex and hard to maintain.

The other approach perhaps is to store these calculations as formulas in a MySQL table for example:

```
assets_loans_on_policies = 10 + 12 + 34 - 45 / 27
```

Where each number in the above is the ID of the corresponding row in the coordinates table. The issue with this approach is storing these formulas in the table. The formula column will have something like this

```
10 + 12 + 34 - 45 / 27
```

The issue here is extracting the individual id's first and then fetching corresponding row value and then calculate. The extracting of these id's become furthermore difficult when its complex and has MAX(value), MIN(value), etc. There are some calculations that are pretty complex.

Any other approach I could take? I need some direction to structure this so in the future many such calculations will be added and should be maintainable.

Comment: What are the restrictions on those formulas? This seems to be stretching the idea of a relational database to an extreme (doing yet unknown operations on an unknown table structure). This can be similar to the complexity of a report designers, which you basically seem to require here (just for formulas). Some restrictions I can think of: you know all formulas and could hardcode them, adding new formulas requires an admin; the values are not needed inside mysql (e.g. to select or sort), the app can evaluate them; the app generates sql code to get the result, the user knows/doesn't know sql